# PHP: Optimize Find-and-replace procedure of many strings in single string

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace, autolink

I'm auto-linking profiles existing on my site in blogpost texts which contain the profile names. To do so I...

1) ...extract currently ~500 rows (only?) from 4 different MySQL tables - containing different types of profiles - in a single database using 4 individual queries.

2) ...str_replace() every profile name individually with a link in the blogpost text, if that profile name exists (tried putting them in search-replace arrays before and do a single str_replace() as well).

While it does what it is supposed to do, it slows down the Blogpost overview page significantly. Loading 10 Posts on the overview page, in which each content is checked against the occurence of profile names, takes 30+ seconds to load. Without this whole autolink procedure the Blogpost overview page loads quickly.

I believe the culprit is step 2). What can I do to speed up the process of finding and replacing a large number of strings (coming from a database) within a single text string?

Comment: I think that's why most systems use an `@` prefix.  Searching every string with every possible username would be incredibly resource exhaustive.

Comment: This makes sense, but gives the linking responsibility back to the user. Could use such markup to tell php which phrases to check against the database, which likely will be much quicker. However, since I often use larger result lists which contain the profile names, this would result in more manual work each time. Also I wouldn't want my users to bother, in case they write the posts. Thus, auto-linking would still be my preferred solution.

Comment: **Give the linking responsibility to the user**. Do not presume that any given keyword is a potential username or you **will get trolled**. Someone's going to register as "the" or "a" and your posts will become a giant mess of links. People know how to use garbage like BBCode, they can figure out how to @ like Twitter.

Comment: Right. Didn't think of such exploits. I'll go along your suggested path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Devon's and @tadman's recommendations it's now the users obligation to take care of linking profiles. However I needed the option to link to profiles which do not exist at the time of post writing but which might be created later. Users now tag any existing or future profile when writing a post by including their name in curly braces. These are found by performing a [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and search the database for the profile name inside the braces.

```
private function link_profile($name) {
    // Put your database search(es) here
    // Create link to profile
    return $link_to_profile;
}

$text = preg_replace_callback("/\{(.*)\}/Usi", "link_profile", $text);
```

In my previous ressource-exhaustive ansatz there were up to 5N [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) calls for N profiles in the database, since variations of the profile name where considered. Now there are between N and 4N database calls at most for N profiles marked in the post text, since 4 different profile types living in individual DB tables might need to be searched for. The new procedure decreases the Blog loading time to ~3s, marking an improvement by more than a factor of 10 compared to the former method.